# Robot Framework: How to get xpath of an element?

Tags: html, xpath, frameworks, robotframework

I am trying to retrieve the id of a parent (grand-grand-parent) element.

All the information I have is that //div[@class="preset_name"] is "all". Knowing that, I need to retrieve "preset_3" (as a string) using any of the Robot Framework keywords.
How would I do that? Or how can I obtain the full xpath of "all"?

```html
<table id="preset_list">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="preset_0">
      <td>
        <div class="preset_title_line">
          <div class="preset_button_group">
            <button class="preset_button">Apply</button>
          </div>
          <div class="preset_name">Factory default</div>
        </div>
        <div class="preset_sections">System, Network, Sources, EDID, Channels, Automatic File Upload, Touch screen, Output ports</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="preset_1">
      <td>
       ...
```

Comment: to OP: Please, never post XML/HTML (or any kind of codes) as image. Post the text instead. The latter is more useful since people can use it to test their XPath against. Thanks

Comment: Show us what you've tried. This looks like a relatively straight-forward problem that can be solved with a simple xpath expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath should be:

```
 Get Element Attribute  xpath=(//div[@class="preset_name"][text()='all']/../../..)@id
```

(I've never used Robot, but I think it is the correct sintax)

Comment: You're missing a space after "Get Element Attribute" -- in this robot syntax keywords and arguments are separated by two or more spaces.

Comment: @StriterAlfa Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter `tr` that contains `//div[@class="preset_name"] = "all"`, and then return the corresponding `id` attribute :

```
//tr[.//div[@class='present_name'] = 'all']/@id
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy if you are using "relative xpath helper chrome extension".

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/finding-relative-xpath-made-easy-syam-sasi?trk=prof-post

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: Its well explained in that link.